# rails: How to do that when you enter one field in a html form, the second field is calculated and stored in a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1) entry form contains one field (long text) and submit button;

2) stored in the database (and displayed to the user when viewing) two fields: one -  from form,  the second - calculated based on the one

how to do?

**update:** what i do:

1) rails new forstackoverflow

2) cd forstackoverflow/

3) rails generate scaffold Note desc:text word_count:integer

4) vim app/views/notes/_form.html.erb

5) Delete div :

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :word_count %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :word_count %>
  </div>
```

6) **and i want calculate and save to db word_count, but not know how**

Comment: You might have to provide a bit more detail.  Do you have code you have tried that you can post and/or can you explain what you want in concrete terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edited***

If you are using scaffolding, the params are automatically saved to database when form is submitted, which you do **not** want.

You will need to require the param in your controller using [strong params](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). Access the param using `params[input]`. Apply logic and save separate params to database exclusively in your controller.

The specific method of word_count can be done like this:

```
string.split.size
```

So in the model, make sure you have created two attributes, one for the string and one for the result of word_count. For now let us assume that you are using "words" for string, and "word_count" for total words in string.

In your view create a form field labeled "words", which will be sent to the params hash as such: `form[words]`.

In the controller under the create action, add the following:

```
@form.words = params[:form][:words]
@form.word_count = @form.words.split.size
@form.save
```

Answer (score 1):

Do that in model callback, let's say, `before_save`. Here's an example:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save do
    self.word_count = self.desc.to_s.split.size
    # to_s just in case self.desc would be nil
  end
end
```

This way each time the model is saved, it will save new word count.